# How to find a user address using the console in Hyperledger Sawtooth?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

- How to find user addresses in hyperledger sawtooth?
- How to register a user on sawtooth validator node?
- Is there anything similar to account in ethereum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concrete thing called 'user' out of the box in sawtooth. What it does have is the ability to set which keys are authorized to do things like change settings and submit transactions.

A sawtooth application can, and probably some have, implemented user and ID management as sawtooth does provide underlying tools to exploit that.

A good start would be to follow the path to the developer documentation from the github main page.

Comment: what database sawtooth uses to store data?

Comment: LMDB is used for journal, data and chain